# How parseInt get its value

Tags: c#, javascript

```
parseInt('bcedfg',16)
```

Base on this code I am getting *773855* in a JavaScript,

I go through the conversion table , and not sure how to get this "773855" value

my question is how parseint come out with this "773855" value , because I wanted to translate this tiny code in to a c# code , and is that any similar way in c# allow me to get this "773855" value

Comment: The problem here is the "bcedfg" is be interpreted as hex(base: 16). Yet the hex scale rolls over at "f".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Convert.ToInt32`:

```
Convert.ToInt32(theString, 16)
```

It uses this overload:

```
public static int ToInt32(string value, int fromBase)
```

Note that you will get `FormatException` because of the `g` in the string:

> **FormatException**
> **value contains a character that is not a valid digit in the base specified by fromBase**. The exception message indicates that there are no digits to convert if the first character in value is invalid; otherwise, the message indicates that value contains invalid trailing characters.

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx)

You're not getting error in javascript as js tends to "forgive" too much errors, this one one of those examples.

Comment: Won't that throw a `FormatException` due to the `g` character?

Comment: Thx gdoron as in Javascript it does not return an error , but in c# it does, but once i remove the g it is getting a same value as the js..thx for the answer

Answer (score 10):

The `bcedfg` is being interpreted as hex(base: `16`). Yet the hex scale rolls over after `f` so, in javascript, the `g` and everything after it is being removed before converting. With that said, here's how the conversion works:

```
decValueOfCharPosition = decValueOfChar * base ^ posFromTheRight
```

so:

```
b = 11 * 16^4 = 11 * 65536 = 720896
c = 12 * 16^3 = 12 * 4096 = 49152
d = 13 * 16^2 = 13 * 256 = 3328
e = 14 * 16^1 = 14 * 16 = 224
f = 15 * 16^0 = 15 * 1 = 15
```

Once you know the decimal value for each character's position, just add them together to get the converted decimal value:

```
b(720896) + c(49152) + d(3328) + e(224) + f(15) = 773855
```

C and it's offspring are not so lenient when it comes to the input. Instead of removing the first invalid character and any characters that may follow after, C throws a [`Format Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx). To work around this to get the javascript functionality you must first remove the invalid character and it's followings, then you can use:

```
Convert.ToInt32(input, base)
```

*I didn't include a way to remove invalid characters due to there being multiple ways of doing as such and my subpar knowledge of C*

Comment: Thx for your explaination SReject